# Why ASP.NET Ajax ColorPickerExtender control returns nothing when the TextBox ReadOnly set to "True"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I am using an Ajax ColorPickerExtender control on a TextBox in my web Page. It works fine when the TextBox ReadOnly Property is "False", but it returns nothing when I change it to "true". what is causing this?

Html:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" 
        runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" 
    runat="server" 
    ClientIDMode="Static" 

    style="margin-top: 0px" 
    ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button
    ID="Button1"
    runat="server"

    Text="Set Color" />
<cc1:ColorPickerExtender ID="TextBox3_ColorPickerExtender2" 
    runat="server" 
    BehaviorID="TextBox3_ColorPickerExtender2" 
    TargetControlID="TextBox3">
</cc1:ColorPickerExtender>
<p>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" 
        runat="server" 
        Text="My Color"></asp:Label>
</p>
```

C#:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("#" + TextBox3.Text);
}
```

Comment: take the `ImageButton` and set `PopupControlId` of this ImageButton in Ajax Color Extender.

Comment: `Extender control 'ColorPickerExtender1' cannot extend 'ImageButton19'. Extender controls of type 'AjaxControlToolkit.ColorPickerExtender' cannot extend controls of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton'.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the colorpicker that returns nothing, it's the texbox.

This happens for any textbox that is marked as readonly, and it's basically how the ASP.Net Framework ensures that the readonly textboxes value can not change by user input from the browser.

To work around this, set the textbox to readonly using the following code, in your PageLoad event.

```
if (!IsPostBack)
    TextBox3.Attributes.Add("readonly","readonly");
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code :

```
<script>
    function setColor() {
        var label = document.getElementById('Label1');
        var txtVal = document.getElementById('TextBox1').value;
        label.style.color = '#' + txtVal;
    }
</script>
```

Add above code inside `<head></head>` tag and add below code inside Form..

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" ClientIDMode="Static" ReadOnly="true" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <cc1:ColorPickerExtender runat="server" BehaviorID="TextBox1_ColorPickerExtender" PopupButtonID="imgButton" TargetControlID="TextBox1" ID="TextBox1_ColorPickerExtender"></cc1:ColorPickerExtender>
        <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="imgButton" ImageUrl="~/painter-palette.png" />
        <input type="button" value="Set Color" onclick="setColor();" />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Text="My Color"></asp:Label>
```

please mark it as answer if it solves your problem

Comment: When I click on the Button to change the Label Back Color to the desired one, It disappears.

Comment: Because your page refreshes on button click..Try Javascript or Jquery instead

Comment: But it does not disappear When the TextBox ReadOnly set to “False”. It is not the reason I think.

Comment: Isn't there any other way to get the selected text?

Comment: Thanks. But I need to do it on the server side.

Comment: May i ask the reason for downvoting my answer??

Comment: I did not do it. Someone I think downvote it  but I vote as a useful to make it better.

Comment: Please Mark it as answer